# react-native how to get deviceSize on jest

Tags: react-native, responsive-design, screen, jestjs, mobile-devices

I am writing a test code on `responsiveStyles` but I am in trouble because I don't know how to get device width by Jest(testCode)

`Xcode Simlulator` is quite do well `reponsiveStyles` 
but Jest Code isn't changed while device is changed

```
export const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width / PixelRatio.get();
export const devieceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height / PixelRatio.get();
```